# About pointers after fork()

Tags: c, unix, pointers, process, fork

This is sort of a technical question, maybe you can help me if you know about C and UNIX (or maybe it is a really newbie question!)

A question came up today while analizing some code in our Operative Systems course. We are learning what it means to "fork" a process in UNIX, we already know it creates a copy of the current process parallel to it and they have separate data sections.

But then I thought that maybe, if one creates a variable and a pointer pointing at it before doing fork(), because the pointer stores the memory address of the variable, one could try to modify the value of that variable from the child process by using that pointer.

We tried a code similar to this in class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
    int value = 0;
    int * pointer = &value;
    int status;
    
    pid_t pid;
    
    printf("Parent: Initial value is %d\n",value);
    
    pid = fork();
    
    switch(pid){
    case -1: //Error (maybe?)
        printf("Fork error, WTF?\n");
        exit(-1);
        
    case 0: //Child process
        printf("\tChild: I'll try to change the value\n\tChild: The pointer value is %p\n",pointer);
        (*pointer) = 1;
        printf("\tChild: I've set the value to %d\n",(*pointer));
        
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
    }
    
    while(pid != wait(&status)); //Wait for the child process
    
    printf("Parent: the pointer value is %p\nParent: The value is %d\n",pointer,value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you run it, you'll get something like this:

> Parent: Initial value is 0
>
> Child: I'll try to change the value
>
> Child: The pointer value is 0x7fff733b0c6c
>
> Child: I've set the value to 1
>
> Parent: the pointer value is 0x7fff733b0c6c
>
> Parent: The value is 0

It's obvious that the child process didn't affect at all the parent process. Frankly, I was expecting some "segmentation fault" error, because of accessing a not permitted memory address. But what really happened?

Remember, I'm not looking for a way to communicate processes, that's not the point. What I want to know is what did the code do. Inside the child process, the change is visible, so it DID something.

My main hypothesis is that pointers are not absolute to memory, they are relative to the process' stack. But I haven't been able to find an answer (no one in class knew, and googling I just found some questions about process communication) so I'd like to know from you, hopefully someone will know.

Thanks for taking your time reading!

Comment: you can put the `printf("Parent: the pointer value is %p\nThe value is %d\n",pointer,value);` in the default case of the `switch()`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: "*Frankly, I was expecting some "segmentation fault" error, because of accessing a not permitted memory address.*" That makes no sense. Think about it. The code the child executes is perfectly legal. The only question is -- does it or doesn't it affect the parent?

Comment: in  each process, due to each process thinks it has all of memory and due to dynamic address translation, the pointer is the (effective) same place in each process address space.  You did not actually change the value in the parent process when changing value in the child process.  They are two different (effective) address spaces.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The key here is the concept of a virtual address space.

Modern processors (Say anything newer then a 80386) have a memory management unit which maps from a per process virtual address space to physical memory pages under control of the kernel.

When the kernel sets up a process it creates a set of page table entries for that process that define the physical memory pages to virtual address space mapping, and it is in this virtual address space that the program executes.

Conceptually when you fork, the kernel copies the existing process pages to a new set of physical pages and sets up the new processes page tables so that as far as the new process is concerned it appears to be running in the same virtual memory layout as the original one had, while actually addressing entirely different physical memory.

**The detail is more subtle as nobody wants to waste time copying hundreds of MB of data unless such is necessary.**
When the process calls fork() the kernel sets up a second set of page table entries (for the new process), but points them at the same physical pages as the original process, it then sets the flag in both sets of pages to make the mmu consider them read only.....

As soon as either process writes to a page, the memory management unit generates a page fault (due to the PTE entry having the read only flag set), and the page fault handler then allocates a new page from physical memory, copies the data over, updates the page table entry and sets the pages back to read/write. 
In this way, pages are only actually copied the first time either process tries to make a change to a copy on write page, and the slight of hand goes completely unnoticed by either process.

Regards, Dan.

Answer (score 6):

Logically, the `fork()`ed process gets its own, independent copy of more or less the whole state of the parent process.  That couldn't work if pointers in the child referred to memory belonging to the parent.

The details of how a particular UNIX-like kernel makes that work can vary.  Linux implements the child process's memory via copy-on-write pages, which makes `fork()`ing comparatively cheap relative to other possible implementations.  In that case, the child's pointers really do point to the parent process's memory, up until such time that either child or parent tries to *modify* that memory, at which time a copy is made for the child to use.  That all relies on the underlying virtual memory system.  Other UNIX and UNIX-like systems can and have done it differently.

Comment: I don't know much about virtual memory at the moment, so I didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The child modified a pointer that is perfectly legal in its address space because it is a copy of its parent. There was no effect on the parent because the memory is not logically shared. Each process gets to go its separate way after the fork.

UNIX has a number of ways of creating shared memory (where one process can modify memory and have that modification seen by another process), but `fork` is not one of them. And it's a good thing because otherwise, synchronization between the parent and child would be almost impossible.

Comment: But why is it legal? Isn't that memory address owned by the parent? The value is the same

Comment: The child doesn't know or care what the parent owns. Yes, the parent owns that memory address (in its address space). The child also owns that memory address (in its address space). The parent and child start out as copies but can then go their separate ways. The memory spaces are permitted to diverge after the fork, but they are the same up to it.

Comment: So, I assume that pointers don't store absolute memory adresses to physical memory. Is that correct?

Comment: @javierbg That would be impossible for about a dozen reasons. Consider `int a[10000];`. There may not even be any physical memory assigned for that array yet because it may never get populated. Or, consider, on a 64-bit system with 4GB of memory, `int *j = malloc(8000000000);` -- there isn't enough physical memory for that to point to.